# How set php codeigniter Facebook login redirect url for a specific controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-3

I have to two facebook login button. first one in the default controller index function and another in a specific controller index function. when I login from the second page Facebook login I redirect for the default controller.
first page login redirect url: localhost/folderName
second page login redirect url: localhost/folderName/controller

I get username and email from the second login also.but the problem is it is redirect for the localhost/folderName index function not for the my current controller index function. It can be seen correct redirect url from the second page controller Facebook button href parameters. But when it is success redirect for the localhost/folderName.

Answer (score 0):

I added redirect function at the success. when user authenticated redirected for the same page with php codeigniter redirect function.

redirect('http://localhost/folder/controller');